# Storing an array - MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, arrays

Given a Profile table containing details about the user - what are the best ways to store in the database the optional pictures they are allowed.

Every user has one main profile picture - an then three optional extra pictures. For sake of potential expandability and maintainability i thought maybe the three optional images could be stored as an array of some sort (~and this could also be a nullable field if they choose not to have any)

Please could someone advise on the best approach.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose a delimited string might work, that's how I store them.  Not  sure if it's the best way.  Maybe one column for the main, and then one column for all the optional images

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate table to hold the pictures, avoid creating a column that contains CSV data since you will need to split the CSV every time it is used.  Not to mention that updating the column could be a nightmare.

```
create table picture(
    picture_id int,
    picture_file blob, /* If storing the file name use varchar*/
    profile_id int /* FK to USER */
)
```

Then in the `Profile` table indicate the main profile picture via a foreign key to picture.

```
create table user(
    profile_id int,
    profile_picture_id int /* FK to main picture */
)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, don't store them in array-

create a separate table instead and let your profileId be the foreign key for this table.

```
table images(
    profileId int,
    image varchar
)
```